# Apple's Cash Pile

Tags: cash, balance-sheet

According to this [article](http://www.reuters.com/article/2013/02/07/us-apple-greenlight-idUSBRE9160MI20130207) (and many others), Apple has a massive cash pile of 137 billion.  However, if I look at their [Financial Statements](https://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ%3aAAPL&fstype=ii&ei=BBUsUbC_OYqLkgXKmQE), it shows (as of 2012-12-29) they only have 40 billion in Cash and Short Term investments and 72 billion in Total Current Assets.  How do people get the number of 137 billion?

Comment: 97.3B in long term investments. That, plus the cash adds to exactly $137B. See balance sheet you linked to, further down the sheet.

Comment: Why on earth is this considered to be a question about Personal Finance? It should be closed if not deleted!

Comment: @DilipSarwate You (and the other who voted to close) are mistaken. Interpreting public company financial statements **is on-topic**, as it relates to investing. Individual investors *should* ask such questions.

Comment: "they only have 40 billion in Cash" - That phrase should never be uttered in this universe, except maybe in Zimbabwe

Comment: @JohnFx - this is a company valued at nearly $500B on a good day. What would you have them do with this money?

Comment: I think he is commenting on the fact that the word "only" in that sentence is just silly.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Personal Finance `& Money`.

Comment: @oldergod `Personal` qualifies `Money` as well as `Finance`.

Comment: @oldergod: Dilip is correct. I keep trying to convince the moderators that we should make that clearer, and they keep insisting that the confusion it causes isn't a problem.... For non-personal money concerns, try the economic or entrepreneurial areas of Stack Exchange.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Even the font is different. I understand then, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

JoeTaxpayer's comment basically answers my question.  See this link for a more detailed explanation. The article [Getting Apple's Cash Right And Why It's Important](http://seekingalpha.com/article/319116-getting-apple-s-cash-right-and-why-it-s-important) was published January 2012, but makes the issue clear.